# Compile multiple contracts

Tags: solidity, etherscan, solc

When compiling a .sol file that contains multiple contracts you get multiple binaries.

How do I know which one belongs to the root contract?

For example looking at [etherdelta contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#code) code I can see a few contracts but the binary presented eventually by etherscan is the one of contract EtherDelta, which is the root contract.

So I'm asking - when compiling a .sol file with multiple contracts how do I know which contract is the root contract, or in other words, how does etherscan knows that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the name of the contract is given by the contract owner during [etherscan verification](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract2).